# jQuery access DOM that's just been added

Tags: jquery, chaining, dom-manipulation

I am adding an image using jQuery to another DOM-element. Now i wan't to fadeout that image that was added, but it's not going very well, i guess because the image was added after the document was loaded!?

Here is my code

```
$('#t' + u).html('<img style="top: 100px;" src="'+data[dataRnd].img+'"/>').find('img').fadeOut(5000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `html()`, create the `img` as a jQuery DOM Object first. After that you can append it to the container and fade it out.

```
var $img = $('<img style="top: 100px;" src="'+data[dataRnd].img+'"/>');
var $container = $('#t' + u).empty();

$img.appendTo($container).fadeOut(5000);
```

- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DQyC6/)
- [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)
- I used [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) to emulate the "cleansing" effect of `.html()`
- [Creating DOM elements from an HTML string with `$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)

---

Problems will arise because the animation might start before the image is loaded. As @adaneo correctly suggested, the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) method can be used to add an event handler on the image when it is loaded and let that start the animation. This still has some [cross-browser issues (see Caveats)](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/#load1), but you can start the animation in a few seconds in case the `load` event did not fire.

```
$img.on('load', function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(5000);
}).appendTo($container);

setTimeout(function () {
    $img.trigger('load');
}, 2000);
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DQyC6/3/)

Comment: it could create a race condition if the image takes longer to load. i.e you could fade it out without any animation as the image isn't yet being displayed

Comment: @adeneo Well, it works. But it's not elegant to "add to the DOM then read the DOM" when you can create the element and simply add it to the DOM.

Comment: @jammypeach - Yes, added that to my answer!

Comment: @jammypeach You are right about that. Will leave my answer here because it contains useful information.

Comment: @bazmegakapa - how about just using plain js and preloading the image as a "new Image" ? That would maybe help a little with the loading issue.

Comment: @adaneo Unfortunately `onload` on images is not quite reliable cross-browser. You can still use `.load()` and set a timeout for starting the fadeout in a few seconds - in case `onload` did not fire.

Answer (score 1):

The way your doing it should work just fine, but there should be a check for image load, something like this:

```
$('#t' + u)
    .html('<img style="top: 100px;" src="'+data[dataRnd].img+'"/>')
    .children().load(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(5000);
    });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DQyC6/2/)

Comment: +1 for `.load()`, formatted for readability. I still say you should not write/read the DOM when write would suffice. Note that `.load()` still has serious cross-browser problems: [docs - see Caveats part](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/#load1).

Answer (score 0):

bazmegakapa's answer is pretty good, I'd go with that myself but here is another way:

Once the document has been loaded (and the script attached to that event has been run), any HTML added after that isn't available to the script beforehand.

So there are two other ways I know of to select an element that doesn't yet exist:

You could use `.on()` to bind a handler to an element that doesn't yet exist. This isn't something I know alot about but this might help:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Another way is wait until you add the HTML before binding a handler to it - example:

```
$(function(){
    //i run when the doc loads
    $.get('someurl', function(data){
        $('body').append('<img src="'+data+'" id='myNewElem'/>');
        //I run after the element is added to the DOM, so I can select it here
        $('img#myNewElem').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Again I'd go with the previous answer personally, these are just other ways you can accomplish the same thing.

EDIT:

A third option that is a bit more relevant to you is to attach a load() event to the image you add to the page, and fade it out once the image finishes loading.

Example:

```
$('#elem').html('<img src="someSrc" id="myImage">');
$('#myImage').load(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

This would prevent the fade happening before the image is visible on the page.

Hope this helps

Comment: `live()` is deprecated as stated on the page you linked. Please don't suggest it.